# How does this command work?

Tags: command-line, sed

I saw this command on a forum as a question for registering:

```
"date -u +%V$(uname)|sha256sum|sed 's/\W//g'"
```

I think it depends on the time of my PC which changes every second, but the output is still the same every time I try it. So, can someone please explain how this command works?

Comment: Note that while this uses the date command the output does not in fact change every second but every week specifically at 00:00 UTC on the Monday of each week. This is because of the specified format string in which the only date component actually being output is the ISO week number (%V). This is why trying the command repeatedly is giving the same output you would have to wait until the next week to see it change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break this into its constituent parts:

#### The `date` part

- `date -u` : as explained in `man date`, the `-u` flag makes it print the [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)
- `+%V` : the data command takes a format argument which is given after a `+`. For example:

  ```
  $ date +%m/%d/%y
  05/04/14
  ```

  See `man date` for a list of all the formats it can produce. The `%V` means:

  > %V     ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)

  So, this week it will return:

  ```
  $ date +%V
  18
  ```

  And *next week* it will return `19`.
- `$(uname)` : this will simply print the result of the `uname` command which should be `Linux` on a Linux system.

So, putting all that together, the `date` command will print `WeekNumberLinux`:

```
$ date -u +%V$(uname)
18Linux
```

#### The `sha256sum` part

`sha256sum` simply takes an input string and applies a [hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to it. This produces a long string that is unique to the input given:

```
$ date -u +%V$(uname) | sha256sum 
9a93b71d5b2841e649195bc81f8e38600860a040bc368cdbd0cde346b73248a1  -
```

#### The `sed` part

The `sed` commmand uses the susbtitution operator (`s/pattern/replacment/`) which will substitute `pattern` with `replacement`. In this case, the pattern is `\W` which means "All non-word characters", meaning anything that's not `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, not a letter, not a number and not an underscore. This is used to remove the trailing space and `-` from the output of `sha256sum`.

---

So, the command is a simple way of making sure you are not a robot. Since the `date` is printing the current week, your output will always be the same until next week when it will change.

Answer (score 1):

```
date -u +%V$(uname)|sha256sum|sed 's/\W//g'
```

Removes all the non word characters from the `sha256sum` of `date -u +%V$(uname)` command's output.

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ date -u +%V$(uname)
18Linux
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ date -u +%V$(uname)|sha256sum
9a93b71d5b2841e649195bc81f8e38600860a040bc368cdbd0cde346b73248a1  -
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ date -u +%V$(uname)|sha256sum|sed 's/\W//g'
9a93b71d5b2841e649195bc81f8e38600860a040bc368cdbd0cde346b73248a1
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$
```

From `man date`

```
%V -  ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)
-u, --utc, --universal    print or set Coordinated Universal Time
```

Comment: i know that but why the output is the same

Comment: what is the job of +%V

Comment: ok many thanks , but what are the meaning of that part after sed

Comment: you mean i have to explain the sed part.

Comment: yes please . if you don't mind

Comment: `s/\W//g`- searches for the non word characters, if it found any then it replaces the non word characters with null(empty but not a space) and this will apply to all the lines because the global flag `g` is set.

Comment: Actually, it will delete the characters, not replace them with null (`\0`) and the `g` makes it apply to the entire line, it is _always_ applied to all lines. Without the `g` only the 1st occurrence of the pattern _on each line_ will be changed but it will always be applied to all input lines, the `g` does not affect that.